# has_many :through - match existing product category, else create new product category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, :through => :categorizations

  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

**categorization.rb**

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :product_id  # Should I leave these accessible?

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end
```

This is what I'm trying in the terminal:

```
> p1 = Product.create(name: "Product A", description: "Product A description")
> p1.categories
> []
> Category.all
> []
> p1.categories.create(:name => "Cat A")
> p1.categories.find(1).name
> ["Cat A"]
>
> p2 = Product.create(name: "Product B", description: "Product B description")
> p2.categories
> []
> p2.categories.update_attributes(:name => "Cat A")
```

I get an undefined method error for 'update_attributes'.

1. How can I assign a product to a category without making a duplicate category in the database?  (i.e. Since "Cat A" is already created above, how can I assign "p2" to have that same category, while keeping only one record of "Cat A" in the database?)
2. When I want to search for a particular product's categories,  when I type in "p.categories.name" I get back the name of the model "Category".  How can I get the category names back in an array?
3. What's the best way to implement this in a web form?

Answer (score 0):

I hope your category name attribute is unique.

```
@categoryCatA = Category.find_by_name("Cat A")

p1.categories << @categoryCatA

p2.categories << @categoryCatA
```

To get names of all the categories assigned to a certain product, this will return an array:

```
p1.categories.map {|category| category.name}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's curious, I found the answer in a very well written article:

http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3:-tagging